# ViewEntryCollection using OpenNTF Domino API - higher performance than getNthEntry(int i)

Tags: java, lotus-domino

With the OpenNTF Domino API, I'm taking a `ViewEntryCollection` from a view that returns approximately 50k documents and I want to get a subset of these, perhaps 100 at a time but not starting at the first document.

The most obvious solution is looping over each entry using the `getNthEntry(int i)` method in the `ViewEntryCollection` class. However this seems about 20% slower than getting documents using for-each*. The [HCL documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_GETNTHENTRY_METHOD_VEC_JAVA.html) discourages developers from using this method due to performance reasons too and I've yet to test this at scale.

Example code below:

```
    ViewEntryCollection vec = ...get some data in a collection...;
    ViewEntry ve = null;
    while(i < countEnd && (ve = vec.getNthEntry(i)) != null) {
        if(ve.isDocument()) {
            //Do something
        }
        i++;
    }
```

As opposed to

```
    int i=0;
    for(ViewEntry ve : vec) {
        if(ve.isDocument()) {
            //Do some processing here
            i++;
        }
        if(i==this.maxDocs) break;
    }
```

Is there a higher performance way of getting, say, 100 entries starting at entry i where i>0?

*Note: I ran a test using getNthEntry against the for-each loop starting from the first document and returning a few hundred documents.

Many thanks

Comment: The reason for this is, that "GetNthEntry" starts from 1 every time you call it. So you get doc no. 20000, then it counts form 1 to 20000. If you then get doc no. 20001, counting will start over at 1. Thats why Andres solution will be significantly faster: It only counts to 20000 ONCE and then uses pointers to get to the next document instead of counting to 20000 100 times...

Comment: I forgot to add that in the Openntf Domino API documentation, the getNextEntry() method appears to be marked as deprecated but I've just tried it and it works but I have to surpress warnings. 

Comment: Just a bump... What's your final solution?

Answer (score 2):

You may need a combination of `getNth()` and `getNext()` to achieve better results.

Please, have a look at the following method:

```
public List<UserDTO> find(int offset, int limit) {

    ArrayList<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
    ViewNavigator nav = null;
    ViewEntry ve = null, temp = null;
    Document document = null;

    this.openDefaultView(DEFAULT_VIEW_NAME);

    if (view.getEntryCount() > 0) {

        view.setAutoUpdate(false);
        nav = view.createViewNav();
        ve = nav.getNth(offset);

        while ((ve != null) && (users.size() < limit)) {

            if (ve.isValid() && ve.isDocument()) {
                document = ve.getDocument();
                UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
                this.documentToObject(document, userDTO);
                users.add(UserDTO);
                recycle(document);
            }
            temp = nav.getNext();
            recycle(ve);
            ve = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic behind it is relatively simple:

1. The `offset` parameter dictates the number of skipped entries.
2. The `limit` parameter sets the number of entries returned from the view.
3. `ViewNavigator` is the key to achieving better performance.

I hope it helps.

Andre Krepsky

Comment: I forgot to add that in the Openntf Domino API documentation, the getNextEntry() method appears to be marked as deprecated but I've just tried it and it works but I have to surpress warnings.  Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same performance problem, creating a cache of values for a selection field. I converted the code to repeatedly call @DbColumn or @DbLookup using the Evaluate function. At least 10 times faster!

The code: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=fast-view-column-reader

Comment: Ooo.. That's interesting. Did you do this in Java?

Comment: Nope, in LotusScript, but I suppose it could easily be converted to Java. Pretty nifty code if I may say so...

Comment: Code is now available!

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look in the morning 

Comment: Were you able to use the code?

Comment: I'm still looking at it. I've managed to make a bit of a performance increase but I'm just working on something else atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ViewNavigator skip method to quickly jump to the wanted position.

Simple example where offset is the position to jump to:

```
int skipped = viewNav.skip(offset);
if (skipped == offset) {
    ViewEntry currEntry=viewNav.getCurrent();

    ... etc.
}
```

Read more at https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2013085308KLEB9S.htm.